# User clicks cell in a UITableView to reorder, how can I know the index and location of the cell being dragged?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Using the provided reorderControls, the user can tap and hold to drag a cell around to reorder it. How can I know which cell they've selected to drag and the position of that current cell (ie when other cells animate to make room for the floating cell, I want the indices of the cells that moved)?

What I am trying to do is to scroll the view so that cells that are offscreen will be scrolled onscreen if the user wishes to reorder the current cell with an offscreen cell. I cannot use built in behaviour because my setup is:

UIScrollView (parent)

- UITableView (child)

And the UITableView frame is the full size of its contentSize (It does not scroll). I need to scroll the outside UIScrollView relative to where the user is dragging a cell to reorder in the UITableView.

I tried looking through the delegate and datasource functions but no luck so far. Also tried googling and Apple documentation...

Edit: SEEMS LIKE I CAN'T READ DOCUMENTATION. `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` in the delegate protocol gives me what I need.

Solution: create a delegate fro tableview to the scrollview's controller (my tableview is its own delegate). In the proposed index path function, I sent the delegate the cell near the proposedDestinationIndexPath that needs to become visible. This could be that cell itself if the indexpath is 0 or the max. Then in the delegate I calculate the position of that cell using the [view convertPoint:FromView:] function and set the scrollview's content offset to make that cell visible!
Thanks

Comment: Why is the table view in a scroll view? A `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`? Are there other things in the scroll view besides the table view?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes there are a bunch of other stuff like a MKMapView, some labels and imageviews and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, as you drag a cell, the table view automatically scrolls when you get to the top or bottom. It sounds like the use of the scrollview is preventing that from working properly since the table view thinks it is big enough not to scroll. There is no normal API call that will give you the answer you want.

The only thing I can think of that may get you close is the implementation of the `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` table view delegate method.

The `proposedIndexPath` may give you a rough idea where the user has currently dragged the row. You can use that indexPath to ask the table for the `CGRect` of the path. Then translate that to a position within the content view of the scroll view.

This is far from perfect though.

Another possibility might be to add an observer to the `frame` or `center` property of the cell being moved.

Comment: It makes sense that it wouldn't work, since the UITableView basically can't scroll. Thanks for suggesting that method. I've overlooked it, but in the documentation it says `Every time the dragged row is over a destination, the table view sends tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath: to its delegate (if it implements the method). In this method the delegate may reject the current destination for the dragged row and specify an alternative one.` so it may work :)

Comment: Wow it's perfect, it gets calls every time a bottom cell animates out of the way! Thanks. I can calculate the location of that cell and do some math to set the contentOffset of the UIScrollView